# PHPUnit - ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Entity\User::__construct(), 0 passed in <PATH_TO_TEST_FILE> and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Just trying to test my symfony API, I wrote that quick test to get, but the only answer i get is "ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Entity\User::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Users.........\tests\Unit\UserTest.php on line 18 and exactly 1 expected"

Here is my file

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Unit;

use App\Entity\User;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    private User $user;
    
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = new User();
    }


    public function testGetId(): void
    {
        $value = 0;

        $response = $this->user->setId($value);
        $getId = $this->user->getId();
        $getUsername = $this->user->getUsername();

        self::assertInstanceOf(User::class, $response);
        self::assertEquals($value, $getId);
        self::assertEquals($value, $getUsername);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well how many parameters are you passing to the constructor here, `$this->user = new User();`?

Comment: I guess only Id

Comment: Well you guessed wrong. If you were passing _anything_, it would have to be between `new User(` and `);` - but there is _nothing_. (Are you seriously working with a framework like symfony and writing unit tests, without even knowing what _passing a parameter_ looks like?)

Comment: I am pretty new to symfony to be honest and i need to test an API as homework. I just thought I was passing the id to the user in my testGetId function

Comment: What does `testGetId` have to do with this? The error message clearly referred to line 18, and that appears to be `$this->user = new User();` inside `setUp`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass needed parameter to user class

```
 protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->user = new User($parameter); //here
}
```